# How to show complex values after doing dft in opencv

Tags: opencv

```
     Mat fourierTransform(1,final.size()-1, CV_64FC1);
     //Mat fourierTransform;
     Mat ans(1,final.size()-1, CV_64FC1)         
     cv::dft(signal, fourierTransform,cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
```

I am following this approach and then I am stuck at how to obtain the complex part of DFT. Can anybody tell how to about it to obtain it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial on how you can use OpenCV's DFT function:
[Discrete Fourier Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html)

Essentially, it will store the output matrix as a two-channel matrix. The first channel is for real values, and the second channel is for complex values.